# Show ViewController from XIB-file-Button - Swift

Tags: swift, segue, xib, viewcontroller, uitableview

is there a way how to **segue** from a **xib-file** (custom TableViewCell) to another **ViewController** in the Main.storyboard.

There's no possibility to drag a segue, like within the main storyboard.

In the cell I've got a button, from where I want to change the view.
How can I solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Not really an answer, but is there a reason why you use a separate xib instead of the interface builder for layouting the cell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always instantiate a view controller from your Storyboard and present it on button tapped:

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerID") as UIViewController
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: When I use this code, it says 'TableViewCell.swift dies not have a member named presentViewController'. TableViewCell.swift is my swift file to the XIB-file.

Comment: TableViewCell.swift is of the type UITableViewCell and is implemented in a tableViewController in the main storyboard

Comment: You need to be in your ViewController to activate the transition, so the action of pressing the TableViewCell must be implemented in the ViewController and not directly in your view.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define a segue in StoryBoard and specify the `identifier`, like `detail`
2. Perform segue in  `talbeView(_, didSelectRowAtIndexPath)`:

Use `self.performSegueWithIdentifier` to fire a segue

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("detail", sender: nil)
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```